# Grid maze returns tuple instead of char

Tags: python

I solved a BFS maze within the maze class that traverses the maze using breadth first search but I have a test case that requires the maze to return the `char` of the direction the maze with `N` `S` `E` `W` for the direction. My issues is converting the move to `char`, like north move `(-1,0)` to `N` in the final return.

Just a note: I'm new to python so just solving this maze was very hard.

```py
def moves(self):
    moves = list()
    (r, c) = self.location
    for (dr, dc) in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]:  # here is North, South, East, West
        if self.grid[r + dr][c + dc] != 'X':
            moves.append((dr, dc))
    return moves

    ### NEIGHBOR ###

    def neighbor(self, move):
        """Return another Maze instance with a move made."""
        neighbor = Maze(self.grid, self.location)

        (dr, dc) = move
        (r, c) = neighbor.location
        neighbor.location = (r + dr, c + dc)

        return neighbor
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert between a list of tuples to a list of strings, simply define a mapping:

```
dir_to_str = {
    (-1,  0): 'W',
    ( 1,  0): 'E',
    ( 0, -1): 'S',
    ( 0,  1): 'N',
}
```

Now to convert, run it through a loop or list comprehension:

```
[dir_to_str[x] for x in path]
```

So, for instance:

```
>>> path = [
    (0, -1), (0, -1),
    (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0),
    (0, -1), (0, -1),
    (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0),
    (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1),
    (1, 0), (1, 0),
    (0, -1),
    (1, 0), (1, 0),
    (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1),
    (1, 0), (1, 0),
    (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1), (0, -1)
]

>>> xs = [dir_to_str[x] for x in path]

>>> ''.join(xs)
'SSEEEEEESSEEEEESSSEESEESSSSSEESSSSS'
```

---

**EDIT:** See the "changed" lines:

```
from typing import List  # just some annotations to show what the types are

def moves(self) -> List[str]:
    moves = []
    (r, c) = self.location
    for (dr, dc) in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]:
        if self.grid[r + dr][c + dc] != 'X':
            moves.append(dir_to_str[(dr, dc)])  # changed
    return moves

def neighbor(self, move: str):
    neighbor = Maze(self.grid, self.location)
    (dr, dc) = str_to_dir[move]                 # changed
    (r, c) = neighbor.location
    neighbor.location = (r + dr, c + dc)
    return neighbor

def bfs(self, maze, goal):
    path = {maze: list()}
    frontier = [maze]

    while len(frontier) > 0:
        parent = frontier.pop(0)

        for move in parent.moves():
            child = parent.neighbor(move)

            if child not in path:
                path[child] = path[parent] + [move]
                frontier.append(child)

                if child == goal:
                    return path[child]
```

where

```
dir_to_str = {
    (-1,  0): 'W',
    ( 1,  0): 'E',
    ( 0, -1): 'S',
    ( 0,  1): 'N',
}

str_to_dir = {v: k for k, v in dir_to_str.items()}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can implement:
    dir_to_str = {
    (-1,  0): 'W',
    ( 1,  0): 'E',
    ( 0, -1): 'S',
    ( 0,  1): 'N',
    }

into the main return as a `dir_to_str.`

Comment: Or can I implement it in the def somewhere for the return instead of the terminal? Part of me thinks it should be in the ‘moves’ definition but would the ‘main’ interpret it correctly?

Comment: Sure, though you'll need to fix `neighbor()` to use `NWSE`. Just create another mapping, `str_to_dir`.

Comment: Sorry, I’m lost. I could add ‘dir_to_str’ to ‘moves’ and then append the ‘neighbor’ method to include it when it uses ‘moves’? I keep getting an error and I’m not sure why.

Comment: I added neighbor. Could you show me what you mean? Or were you talking about neighbor() in the `main`?

Comment: What's the error you get? It's easiest to just make sure your functions all have their inputs and outputs in some consistent type. Are they all emitting `List[str]`? Or are some of them still emitting `List[Tuple[int, int]]`?

Comment: I've gotten lost in the method we're talking about. Is it easiest to implement the `dir_to_str` in the `main` class or should should I implement it in `moves` and use the reverse in `neighbor`? I feel like there's an easy way to translate the grid into `char` directions but the conversion never works with each grid move translated into a `char` return. I'm missing something. Could you show me in either the `moves` and `neighbor` defs or do you mean to add something in the `main`? Everything seems consistent (with lists) but the return is never the individual direction notation.

Comment: @user12027316 See edit. Note that there's no `char` in Python: you're talking about `str` with length 1.